# ImageButton Cannot be added into the Sliding Menu Drawer

Tags: android

> I am doing a small program in that i have added one drawer which opens on button click, and in that i am able to display Text, Buttons but i want to add ImageButton in that drawer, then it will gives the error.

```
public class slidingDrawerDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageButton slideButton, b1, b2;
SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    slideButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.slideButton);
    slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.SlidingDrawer);


    b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    b2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    OnClickListener(this);

    slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new OnDrawerOpenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened() {
            slideButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.closearrow);
        }
    });

    slidingDrawer.setOnDrawerCloseListener(new OnDrawerCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed() {
            slideButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.openarrow);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Button b = (Button) v;
    Toast.makeText(slidingDrawerDemo.this, b.getText() + " Clicked",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
activity_main.xml

     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@layout/border"
            android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:handle="@+id/slideButton"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dip"
            android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/slideButton"
                android:layout_width="158dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/closearrow" >
            </Button>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="667dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="5dip" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/imagesb" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="405dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/imagesa" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </SlidingDrawer>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and the error is,
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton

Comment: you won't get no answer, if you don't tell what kind of error you get!

Comment: add the activity_main.xml aswell. feels like some minor typo somehwere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there is two possibilities:

1) If you are using ImageButton in your xml file but try to find id of Button:

2) If you are using Button in your xml file but try to find id of ImageButton :

If you are using ImageButton then set on onCreate()

```
  ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
```

If you are using Button then set on onCreate()

```
  Button ib = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Problem is here:

```
 slideButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.slideButton);
```

you have initialize with ImageButton but you in your xml file it is Button..So change

```
 slideButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slideButton);
```

Comment: you are absolutely right piyush gupta....thank you for your time and help....thank you again..